# Docker Run [tag-name to container] returns python: can't open file in Windows

Tags: python, docker, containers

python: can't open file 'Test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory even though I have specified the working directory of the container.

[CMD path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Mtu.png)

Comment: Did you copy or add the file into the docker container when you built the image?

Comment: I copied the file into the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using full path when you try to run something.

```
/home/user/Test.py
```

Comment: It didn't work, I changed my code to: CMD python /home/Test/Test.py

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile and/or docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: I donot have a docker-compose, sharing the Dockerfile:

#"publicly available docker image "python" on docker hub will be pulled"
FROM docker.io/library/python:latest
#"creating directory helloworld in container (linux machine)"
RUN mkdir C:\home\Test
#"copying Test.py from local directory to container's Test folder"
COPY Test.py C:/Users/DataAnalyst/Docker/Test.py
#"running Test.py in container"
CMD python /home/user/Test.py

Comment: As from docs https://hub.docker.com/_/python you could try to run this command:

`docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python:3 python Test.py`

I can see that you're trying to mix Windows locations (C:/Users....) in a linux machine, which could be incorrect.

Comment: This : docker run -it --rm --name helloworldapp -v "$PWD":/home/Test -w C:/Users/DataAnalyst/Docker/ python:3 python Test.py didn't help either...
But when i used docker run -d helloworldapp
I did getting container ID but the program "Test.py" was supposed to print something, it didn't

Comment: The script is meant to use your current folder ($PWD) as mount of container /usr/src/myapp, try to not change it and run the script from the folder you're having your Test.py file

Comment: Thanks Andrea, sorry for taking light years to reply :P, The problem was, my Dockerfile was "Dockerfile.txt". It worked after changing it.

Comment: Good to know! :-)